# Issue with calculating elapsed minutes between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following code to calculate the minutes between the startdate and enddate. It also takes the working hours (9 to 5) into account so that it should not calculate anything outside working hours.

It works fine if startdate and enddate are with in the working hours but if startdate is outside the working hours (before 9 AM), it returns negative number.

```
private static int GetMinutesBetweenTwoDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var minutes = from day in startDate.DaysInRangeUntil(endDate)
                  where !day.IsWeekendDay()
                  let start = Max(day.AddHours(9), startDate)
                  let end = Min(day.AddHours(17), endDate)
                  select (end - start).TotalMinutes;
}

private static DateTime Max(DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
    return new DateTime(Math.Max(a.Ticks, b.Ticks));
}

private static DateTime Min(DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
    return new DateTime(Math.Min(a.Ticks, b.Ticks));
}

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DaysInRangeUntil(this DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (int)(end.Date - start.Date).TotalDays)
        .Select(dt => start.Date.AddDays(dt));
}

public static bool IsWeekendDay(this DateTime dt)
{
    return dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
           || dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: dont write linq so you can debug your code. after finding the issue then start to write proper linq for it (if you like).

Comment: What about Bank Holidays?

Comment: @batwad I have a separate logic which removes the bank holiday minutes from total elapsed minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to filter the cases with `end <= start` which can happen if start date time is after working time end or end date time is before working time start. The easier would be to insert additional `where` clause:

```
private static int GetMinutesBetweenTwoDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var minutes = from day in startDate.DaysInRangeUntil(endDate)
                  where !day.IsWeekendDay()
                  let start = Max(day.AddHours(9), startDate)
                  let end = Min(day.AddHours(17), endDate)
                  where end > start
                  select (end - start).TotalMinutes;
    return (int)minutes.Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, there is this very usefull library for time periods :

[CodeProject : Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET)